# Two figures side by side

Tags: floats, captions, subfloats

How can I put two figures side-by-side? Not two sub-figures, but two actual figures with separate "Fig.: bla bla" captions.  A figure is supposed to spread over the entire text width, but I have two figures which are narrow and long, and I need to save the space in order to withstand the pages limit.

Comment: @Matthew-leingang answer works for beamer presentations too

Answer (score 283, accepted):

You can put `minipage`s inside a `figure` environment and get separate captions for each of them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
How can I put two figures side-by-side? Not two sub-figures, but two actual figures
with separate "Fig.: bla bla" captions. A figure is supposed to spread over the
entire text width, but I have two figures which are narrow and long, and I need to
save the space in order to withstand the pages limit.

\lipsum

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-a} % first figure itself
        \caption{first figure}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-b} % second figure itself
        \caption{second figure}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image: sample code rendering]

I was surprised to discover two `\captions` in the same `figure` environment actually work as desired.

HT: [LaTeX Matters](http://texblog.wordpress.com/2007/08/01/placing-figurestables-side-by-side-minipage/) via Google

Comment: This is what I ended up with.  It appears that the actual semantics of figure is: "Everything with a caption in this environment is a figure, and it all floats together".

Comment: I normally put a `\hfill` between the `minipage`s to spread them evenly over the text width.

Comment: This worked nicely, but then I wanted another line of pictures underneath. Is that possible somehow?

Comment: I'm confused. Why don't you have the command `\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{image.pdf}` anywhere?

Comment: @CharlieParker: I wrote and used the `\exedout` macro to draw a black box for a sample image.  Otherwise the example code won't comple without an image.pdf to go with it.  Now we have the [`mwe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe) package to provide sample placeholder images.

Comment: @CharlieParker: I went ahead and updated the answer using the `mwe` package and placeholder images.  I hope that's less confusing.

Comment: sorry for being annoying, is it ok if you insert an image of what I'm supposed to see? (though thanks so far)

Comment: @CharlieParker: sure.  see edit.

Comment: Note that you mustn't have an empty line between the minipages or you won't end up with the two columns.

Comment: @jsaven: You're absolutely right.  An empty line introduces a `\par` token which creates a new paragraph.

Comment: What if the images [A] and [B] are not the same height? Could you extend your answer to show how to vertically align the two captions?

Comment: @gen: Just use the `[b]` optional argument after each of the `\begin{minipage}` commands.  That aligns the two at their bottom edges.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Thanks! However, I found that to be `[t]` rather than `[b]`. Otherwise the captions and not the figures of different height themselves will be aligned.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: is it possible to label them as subfigures, i.e. the main figure if Figure 5, the minipage objects are Figure 5a and 5b?

Comment: @Alex: If that's what you want, you should look at `subcaption`.

Comment: I am using the same code in the IEEE conference format in overleaf. But my figures overwrite the text. Am I missing something here? can anyone please help and identify where I am making a mistake.

Comment: @SchaibBinAitaf you should probably create a new question with your code worked down to a minimal working version.  Link to it from here if you like.

Comment: i have applied your code but along with the images, strange text has appeared in my doc. was it because of 'lipsum' pehaps?

Comment: and the figures are at the top of the page rather than after a certain portion of text. how do i move the images?

Comment: The first `\centering` is probably redundant, right?

Answer (score 29):

Since your figures shall be side by side, they are not expected to float independently. So you need just one figure environment for both objects.

Within this figure environment, you may use minipages (like Matthew already suggested). Some additions:

- minipages understand optional alignment parameters to align at top, bottom or center.
- For adding a caption to the minipages, I recommend to use the [subcaption](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf) package. It is part of the feature-rich [caption](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) package.

Nevertheless you could check out the [subfig](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig) package. That task could be handled like subfigures even if you customize the captions such that they look like two independent figures.

Comment: do you have actual code or an example to be used?

Answer (score 26):

The `floatrow`package can easily do that (and many other things) with its floatrow environment:

```
       \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
        \usepackage{lmodern}
        \usepackage{graphicx}
        \usepackage{caption}
         \usepackage{floatrow}%

        \begin{document}

        \begin{figure}[!h]
           \begin{floatrow}
             \ffigbox{\includegraphics[scale = 0.8]{casxinf1}}{\caption{Case  $ x  < 1 $}\label{case1}}
             \ffigbox{\includegraphics[scale = 0.8]{zoom}}{\caption{A zoom}\label{zoom}}
           \end{floatrow}
        \end{figure}

        \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is floatrow still actively maintained?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not sure. Last change dates back to July 2012.

Answer (score 14):

I got this working in a document with *two text columns*, just wanted to share what I did.

In this case, I wanted *one figure* of *two side-by-side images* to appear *within one text column*.

The `\centering` inside the minipages caused trouble so I removed them. Moreover, `\linewidth` (one-column width) needs to be used rather than `\textwidth` (which equals the full two-column width).

Another pitfall is the `width=` parameter of the `\includegraphics`: Since we're within a minipage, this width refers to the *width of the minipage*, not the width of the column.

Here's my code:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img1.png}
  \captionof{figure}{First caption}
  \label{img1}
\end{minipage}
\hspace{.05\linewidth}
\begin{minipage}{.45\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{img2.png}
  \captionof{figure}{Second caption}
  \label{img2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

The `\hspace{.05\linewidth}` makes sure there is some horizontal space between the two captions.

Comment: Since you're already operating in a `figure` environment, what is the advantage of using `\captionof{figure}{...}` instead of the simpler `\figure{...}`? Second, I'm confused by your write-up: you state that you're looking to have two figures within one column -- presumably one above the other, right? -- yet the code you post would place them side-by-side. Third, please don't post just code snippets, but compilable examples that start with `\document{<some class>}` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @mico I tried replacing with ``\figure{...}``, but that gives me a "Caption(s) lost" error. I do wish side-by-side images, but within _one text column_, e.i., not spanning both text colums. I've clarified that now, it was mis-leading before, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I don't get the error message about "Caption(s) lost" when replacing `\captionof` with `\caption`. I expanded your code snippet into an MWE by loading the `graphicx` and `caption` packages; are you maybe loading additional packages that could create some interference?

Comment: why do I get an error die to `\captionof`nsays undefined control sequence... :/