# Two figures side-by-side with inequal height and aligned captions

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment, captions

I have an addition to this question: [Two figures side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5769/two-figures-side-by-side).

Suppose we have two pictures, making them of uneven height. I am looking for a way to *not* use `subfig` and align two figures side-by-side, while keeping the captions vertically aligned.

I've created the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Two Figures Side by Side}
\author{Little Bobby Tables}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\exedout}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path node (LL) {}
    ++ (0.8\textwidth, 0.8\textheight) node (UR) {}
    (LL -| UR) node (LR) {}
    (LL |- UR) node (UL) {};
\draw (LL) rectangle (UR) (LL) -- (UR) (UL) -- (LR);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\exedouttwo}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path node (LL) {}
    ++ (0.8\textwidth, 0.4\textheight) node (UR) {}
    (LL -| UR) node (LR) {}
    (LL |- UR) node (UL) {};
\draw (LL) rectangle (UR) (LL) -- (UR) (UL) -- (LR);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
How can I put two figures side-by-side? Not two sub-figures, but two actual figures
with separate "Fig.: bla bla" captions. A figure is supposed to spread over the
entire text width, but I have two figures which are narrow and long, and I need to
save the space in order to withstand the pages limit.

\lipsum

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering\exedout
\caption{first figure but with more comments than the second picture to see what the different is.}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering\exedouttwo
\caption{second figure}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

It gives the following result:

[image: wrong alignment]

But I need this:

[image: right alignment]

Comment: minipage environments have placement parameters `[c]`, `[t]` and `[b]`, do they help?

Comment: why are you not using the `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{flower1.jpg}`, how are you inserting an image exactly then?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the `[t]` optional argument of `minipage` to align both to the top baseline (i.e. the image baseline / lower line). I also added `%`s to your macros to avoid extra spaces being inserted by the source code line breaks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\exedout}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path node (LL) {}
    ++ (0.8\textwidth, 0.8\textheight) node (UR) {}
    (LL -| UR) node (LR) {}
    (LL |- UR) node (UL) {};
\draw (LL) rectangle (UR) (LL) -- (UR) (UL) -- (LR);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\newcommand{\exedouttwo}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path node (LL) {}
    ++ (0.8\textwidth, 0.4\textheight) node (UR) {}
    (LL -| UR) node (LR) {}
    (LL |- UR) node (UL) {};
\draw (LL) rectangle (UR) (LL) -- (UR) (UL) -- (LR);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
How can I put two figures side-by-side? Not two sub-figures, but two actual figures
with separate "Fig.: bla bla" captions. A figure is supposed to spread over the
entire text width, but I have two figures which are narrow and long, and I need to
save the space in order to withstand the pages limit.

\lipsum

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering\exedout
\caption{first figure but with more comments than the second picture to see what the different is.}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\textwidth}
\centering\exedouttwo
\caption{second figure}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I was looking for. I already tried it with only a single `[t]`, but didn't come up with doing it at both minipages.

Comment: why are you not using the `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{flower1.jpg}`, how are you inserting an image exactly then?

Comment: @CharlieParker: Figures don't have to include `\includegraphics`. They can include any content you like, like a drawing made by the TikZ package in this case. If you want to include the image instead just replace the `\exedout` and `\exedouttwo` macros with `\includegraphics..`.

Answer (score 4):

Is using [`floatrow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) an option?

Note that in the following example I made the two figures narrower by changing `\exedout` and `\exedouttwo`, as `ffigbox` doesn't seem to change `\textwidth` as `minipage` does, hence the two figures would be too wide.

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Two Figures Side by Side}
\author{Little Bobby Tables}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\newcommand{\exedout}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path node (LL) {}
    ++ (0.4\textwidth, 0.8\textheight) node (UR) {}
    (LL -| UR) node (LR) {}
    (LL |- UR) node (UL) {};
\draw (LL) rectangle (UR) (LL) -- (UR) (UL) -- (LR);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\newcommand{\exedouttwo}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path node (LL) {}
    ++ (0.4\textwidth, 0.4\textheight) node (UR) {}
    (LL -| UR) node (LR) {}
    (LL |- UR) node (UL) {};
\draw (LL) rectangle (UR) (LL) -- (UR) (UL) -- (LR);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
How can I put two figures side-by-side? Not two sub-figures, but two actual figures
with separate "Fig.: bla bla" captions. A figure is supposed to spread over the
entire text width, but I have two figures which are narrow and long, and I need to
save the space in order to withstand the pages limit.

\lipsum

\begin{figure}
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox{\caption{first figure but with more comments than the second picture to see what the different is.}}{\exedout}
\ffigbox{\caption{second figure}}{\exedouttwo}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like a good alternative if I need any other configurations like aligning them both at the top.