# Using minipage with subfigure didn't produce side by side figures

Tags: subfloats, minipage

As per [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5770/11134), I tried using `\minipage` with my `\subfigure`, however to no avail. (My figures are still stacked vertically)
I even tried changing `scale` to `width=0.5\textwidth`...

What did I do wrong?

Brief working example:

Also uploaded [**here**](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13223318/sample_latex_files.zip) as a .zip file.

Sorry, I really don't know how to format stuff on here. So it looks messy.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eps2pdf}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[super,numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{color}
% \usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{grrfile}
\usepackage{placeins}
\newcommand{\hilight}[1]{\colorbox{yellow}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\alph{footnote}}
\usepackage[paper=letterpaper,left=1.0in,right=1.0in,top=0.25in,bottom=1.0in,]{geometry}




\begin{document}



\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering

\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{subfigure}[Initial condition]{
   \includegraphics[scale =0.25] {./pngs/profile_L_3lambda_max_1wl_0.png}
   \label{fig:subfig1}
 }
\end{subfigure}
\end{minipage} 


\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
 \begin{subfigure}[DFT]{
   \includegraphics[scale =0.25] {./pngs/profile_L_3lambda_max_1wl_dft_0.png}
   \label{fig:subfig2}
 }\end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}



\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
 \begin{subfigure}[DFT (corner)]{
   \includegraphics[scale =0.25] {./pngs/profile_L_3lambda_max_1wl_dft_0_X.png}
   \label{fig:subfig3}
 }\end{subfigure}
\end{minipage}


\label{myfigure}
\caption{Initial condition, $L=3\lambda_{max}, \text{k}=1, G=0.333,S=100, M=35.1, \text{Pr=7.02}, E=0, Ra=0$}
\end{figure}




\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{subfigure}[Initial condition]{
   \includegraphics[scale =0.25] {./pngs/profile_L_3lambda_max_1wl_Rup.png}
   \label{fig:subfig4}
 }\quad
\end{subfigure}

 \begin{subfigure}[DFT]{
   \includegraphics[scale =0.25] {./pngs/profile_L_3lambda_max_1wl_dft_Rup.png}
   \label{fig:subfig5}
 }\end{subfigure} 

\label{myfigure}
\caption{Rupture condition, , $L=3\lambda_{max}, \text{k}=1, G=0.333,S=100, M=35.1, \text{Pr=7.02}, E=0, Ra=0$}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: rather than using the `subfigure` package, a lot of folks prefer the `subcaption` package- would you be interested in seeing a solution using it?

Comment: @cmhughes sure. And thats because the `subfigure` package is "deprecated"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If, for some reason, you can't use another package but the obslote `subfigure` package, here's one way to achieve what you want; basically, don't leave blank lines between `subfigure` environment (those blank lines are `\par` commands ending a paragraph); also, instead of using `scale=<value>` it could be safer to use `width=<length>` so that you can guarantee that the total width for the three images won't surpass the `\textwidth` (of course, if you can guarantee the condition using `scale`, then feel free to use that option instead); try not to leave spurious blank spaces (your code has some of those too which I removed using `%` at the end of some lines):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{grrfile}
\usepackage[paper=letterpaper,left=1.0in,right=1.0in,top=0.25in,bottom=1.0in,]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[Initial condition]{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth] {./pngs/profile_L_3lambda_max_1wl_0.png}
   \label{fig:subfig1}
 }%
\end{subfigure}\hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[DFT]{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{./pngs/profile_L_3lambda_max_1wl_dft_0.png}
   \label{fig:subfig2}
 }%
\end{subfigure}\hfill
 \begin{subfigure}[DFT (corner)]{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{./pngs/profile_L_3lambda_max_1wl_dft_0_X.png}
   \label{fig:subfig3}
 }%
\end{subfigure}%
\caption{Initial condition, $L=3\lambda_{max}, \text{k}=1, G=0.333,S=100, M=35.1, \text{Pr=7.02}, E=0, Ra=0$}
\label{fig:myfigure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the example, I removed some of the packages that were not essential for the solution.

The `demo` option for graphicx simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: Hi! sorry I got a little sick with the flu. Will try this suggestion soon! Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! I hope the flu is gone and you're better.