# Caption on side by side matrices

Tags: table-of-contents, floats, captions, matrices

I have two matrices side by side, like this:

```
\[
  \left[\begin{array}{cc}
    a & b \\
    c & d
  \end{array}\right] \qquad
  \left[\begin{array}{cc}
    e & f \\
    g & h
  \end{array}\right]
\]
```

[image: The result is this:]

I want to:

1. have a caption to both matrices
2. if possible, have it recognized as figure (so it appears on the figure list).

Comment: Similar question: [Two figures side by side](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5769/two-figures-side-by-side)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not entirely sure whether this satisfies all your constraints (since I'm not putting the sub-captions in the LoF):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \[A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
      a & b \\
      c & d
    \end{array}\right]\]
    Short caption for matrix~$A$
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \[A'=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
      e & f \\
      g & h
    \end{array}\right]\]
    Short caption for matrix~$A'$
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{A caption to the entire figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The idea is to place two `minipage`s of `.5\linewidth` inside a `figure`. Yes, the `figure` environment can contain anything inside of it, even mathematics, even a `tabular`, even an image. It merely acts as a place holder that floats around.

Within each `minipage` the contents can be supplied in whichever way you like. As I've done in the above example, a display equation is used, together with regular centred text below. You can modify the "short captions" to be `\small` or `\footnotesize`, if needed.

If the requirement is to have the "short captions" form part of the LoF, some more work is required.

Answer (score 4):

In the following MWE you will find a solution for your problem using package `subfig`:

```
%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84021/caption-on-side-by-side-matrices
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section{My Work}

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \subfloat[Image A][The Image A%
    \label{subfig:imageA}]{%
    \begin{math}
    \left[\begin{array}{cc}
    a & b \\
    c & d
    \end{array}\right]
    \end{math}
    }% 
   \qquad   % Distance Image A and B 
  \subfloat[Image B][The Image B%
    \label{subfig:ImageB}]{% 
    \begin{math}
    \left[\begin{array}{cc}
    e & f \\
    g & h
    \end{array}\right]
    \end{math}
  } 
  \caption{Image with two subfigures}
  \label{fig:ImageAB}
\end{figure} 

In figure~\ref{fig:ImageAB} you see two subfigure~\ref{subfig:imageA} and \ref{subfig:ImageB}.

\end{document}
```

With `\subfloat` you define a sub figure, `\qquad` is the distance between the two sub figures. You can reference the complete figure or both of the sub figures (see last sentence in MWE). A list of figures shows your figure as wanted.