# Place several plots on one page

Tags: pgfplots

I have 4 plots that should be placed on the same page.  Does anyone know how to do it? I need to have a caption/title under each plot (and I cannot place it above the plot as there are numbers), a legend can be common to all plots.

Here is the code:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines*=left,
    ybar,
    ymin=0,ymax=1,
    enlarge x limits=0.5,
    bar width=10pt,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={percentage, \%},
    symbolic x coords={P,R},
    xtick=data,
    major x tick style = transparent,
    ymajorgrids = true,
    tick align=outside,
    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style={anchor=mid west, rotate=90},  
 %   nodes near coords,
  %  nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    ]
\addplot [fill=red!50]coordinates {(P,0.4) (R,0.3)  };
\addplot [fill=red!50]coordinates {(P,0.5) (R,0.5)};
legend{min1,min2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Results P} 
\label{fig:3}
\end{figure}



\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines*=left,
    ybar,
    ymin=0,ymax=1,
    enlarge x limits=0.5,
    bar width=10pt,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={percentage, \%},
    symbolic x coords={P,R},
    xtick=data,
    major x tick style = transparent,
    ymajorgrids = true,
    tick align=outside,
    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style={anchor=mid west, rotate=90},  
 %   nodes near coords,
  %  nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    ]
\addplot [fill=green!50]coordinates {(P,0.94) (R,0.5)  };
\addplot [fill=violet!50]coordinates {(P,0.6) (R,0.6)};
\legend{min1,min2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Results I} 
\label{fig:4}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines*=left,
    ybar,
    ymin=0,ymax=1,
    enlarge x limits=0.5,
    bar width=10pt,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={percentage, \%},
    symbolic x coords={P,R},
    xtick=data,
    major x tick style = transparent,
    ymajorgrids = true,
    tick align=outside,
    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style={anchor=mid west, rotate=90},  
 %   nodes near coords,
  %  nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    ]
\addplot [fill=green!50]coordinates {(P,0.5) (R,0.7)  };
\addplot [fill=violet!50]coordinates {(P,0.4) (R,0.9)};
legend{min1,min2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Results U} 
\label{fig:5}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines*=left,
    ybar,
    ymin=0,ymax=1,
    enlarge x limits=0.5,
    bar width=10pt,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={percentage, \%},
    symbolic x coords={P,R},
    xtick=data,
    major x tick style = transparent,
    ymajorgrids = true,
    tick align=outside,
    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style={anchor=mid west, rotate=90},  
 %   nodes near coords,
  %  nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    ]
\addplot [fill=green!50]coordinates {(P,0.1) (R,0.6)  };
\addplot [fill=green!50]coordinates {(P,0.2) (R,0.9)};
legend{min1,min2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Results X} 
\label{fig:6}
\end{figure}
```

I would appreciate any suggestions!
I tried `\matrix` environment but cannot add a caption into each plot. A general title to all 4 plots would be nice as well.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate or helpful answers: [Two figures side by side](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5769/two-figures-side-by-side)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an option using the `subcaption` package

[image: screenshot]

I have also taken the liberty to introduce a style called, `mystyle`, which avoids having to repeat too much of the code.

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\pgfplotsset{
every axis/.append style={width=\textwidth},
mystyle/.style={
axis lines*=left,
    ybar,
    ymin=0,ymax=1,
    enlarge x limits=0.5,
    bar width=10pt,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={percentage, \%},
    symbolic x coords={P,R},
    xtick=data,
    major x tick style = transparent,
    ymajorgrids = true,
    tick align=outside,
    nodes near coords,
    every node near coord/.append style={anchor=mid west, rotate=90},  
}
}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    mystyle
    ]
\addplot [fill=red!50]coordinates {(P,0.4) (R,0.3)  };
\addplot [fill=red!50]coordinates {(P,0.5) (R,0.5)};
\legend{min1,min2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Results P} 
\label{fig:3}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    mystyle,
 %   nodes near coords,
  %  nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    ]
\addplot [fill=green!50]coordinates {(P,0.94) (R,0.5)  };
\addplot [fill=violet!50]coordinates {(P,0.6) (R,0.6)};
\legend{min1,min2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Results I} 
\label{fig:4}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    mystyle
    ]
\addplot [fill=green!50]coordinates {(P,0.5) (R,0.7)  };
\addplot [fill=violet!50]coordinates {(P,0.4) (R,0.9)};
\legend{min1,min2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Results U} 
\label{fig:5}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    mystyle
    ]
\addplot [fill=green!50]coordinates {(P,0.1) (R,0.6)  };
\addplot [fill=green!50]coordinates {(P,0.2) (R,0.9)};
\legend{min1,min2}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Results X} 
\label{fig:6}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Global caption goes here}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for help! It works nicely. Do you know any trick how to make a single legend (with 2 criteria min1, min2) for all plots in case the colors in the plots are the same? So it does not show the same thing under each subfigure...