# Latex code for two tikz fig. side by side in a single column format

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to place these two .tikz Fig. side by side in a single column format. Please suggest me latex code for this.

```
\begin{figure} [H]
\begin{center}
\input{states2_zeta.tikz}
\end{center}
\caption{Output current of controlled zeta converter}
{\label{sec4:Zeta converter:load current}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure} [H]
\begin{center}
\input{states4_zeta.tikz}
\end{center}
\caption{Output voltage of controlled zeta converter}
{\label{sec4:Zeta converter:output voltage}}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site! I suppose you want to keep the caption for each figure. You can use two `minipage`s as described in [Two figures side by side](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5770)

Answer (score 1):

Here on TeX.Se are planty of similar questions, so yours is probably duplicate ... Anyway, try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{*{2}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image}%\input{states2_zeta.tikz}
\caption{Output current of controlled zeta converter}
    \label{sec4:Zeta converter:load current}
    &
\includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image}%{states4_zeta.tikz}
\caption{Output voltage of controlled zeta converter}
    \label{sec4:Zeta converter:output voltage}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, instead of example images you use your TikZ picture.