# Two figures side by side in Tufte-Latex

Tags: floats, captions, tufte

I'm using Tufte-LaTeX and I have two small figures that I would like to appear side by side.
I read this question and answer about putting [two figures side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5769/two-figures-side-by-side?newreg=c0a4130aaf864a809ecbf4d7b5749c87). I tried this with Tufte-LaTeX, but it only prints the first caption. 
Also, it would be nice if the captions appeared each under its own figure, like in example I cited.
Is there a way to do this? Thanks!

PS

Here is the example I am using

```
\documentclass[nohyper,titlepage,nols]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
How can I put two figures side-by-side? Not two sub-figures, but two actual
figures
with separate "Fig.: bla bla" captions. A figure is supposed to spread over the
entire text width, but I have two figures which are narrow and long, and I need
to
save the space in order to withstand the pages limit.

\lipsum

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-a} % first figure itself
        \caption{first figure}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-b} % second figure itself
        \caption{second figure}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: can you show, what you try? in form of small, complete document beginning with `\documentclass{tufte-book}` (or what you used) and ending with `\end{document}`. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: Hi,  I added the example I am using. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

like this?

[image]

it seem that simple solution with `minipage` doesn't work in `tufte-book` document class (the first caption is lost). however, with `\ffigbox` is possible to solve your problem, but captions are below figures and not outsides of main text as it is default `tufte` style:

```
\documentclass[nohyper,titlepage,nols]{tufte-book}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage{floatrow}   % <--- added



\begin{document}
How can I put two figures side-by-side? Not two sub-figures, but two actual figures with separate "Fig.: bla bla" captions. A figure is supposed to spread over the entire text width, but I have two figures which are narrow and long, and I need to save the space in order to withstand the pages limit.
\begin{figure}[!h]
   \begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}%
        {\caption{first figure}\label{fig:example-1}}
\hfill
\ffigbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}%
        {\caption{second figure}\label{fig:example-2}}
   \end{floatrow}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I like it because it works also with the real document! Thanks!