# How to place two figures containing tables side by side?

Tags: tables, floats

I have two 3x3 tables, each grid contains a plot, looks something like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\subcaptionbox{\label{} SEM}{\includegraphics[width = 0.1\textwidth]{area4_sem}}  & \subcaptionbox{\label{} EDS Overview}{\includegraphics[width =         0.1\textwidth]{area4_all}} & \subcaptionbox{\label{} Cu}{\includegraphics[width =0.1\textwidth]{area4_Cu}} \\
\subcaptionbox{\label{EDS Si map Pb} Pb}{\includegraphics[width =0.10\textwidth]{area4_Pb}}  & \subcaptionbox{\label{} Si}{\includegraphics[width=     0.10\textwidth]{area4_Si}} & \subcaptionbox{\label{EDS Si map Sn} Sn}{\includegraphics[width = 0.10\textwidth]{area4_Sn}} \\
\subcaptionbox{\label{} Ni}{\includegraphics[width = 0.10\textwidth]    {area4_Ni}}  & \subcaptionbox{\label{} Ba}{\includegraphics[width =     0.10\textwidth]{area4_Ba}} & \subcaptionbox{\label{} O}{\includegraphics[width =     \textwidth]{area4_O}} \\
\end{tabular}
\caption{X-ray Map of Si-Interconnect Area}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

So I have two tables like this, how can I place these tables side by side?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). It would be very uselful if you make your code compilable, by adding `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Please use `\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}` such that anybody can compile your document. What is the use of `\label{}` in your code?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5769/two-figures-side-by-side?rq=1 Replace the `\includegraphics` in the highest voted answer with your `tabular`.

Comment: Only the captions need to be in minipages.  So you can also place the tabulars beside each other (\hfil but no blank line) or use a 6x3 tabular, then add the captions in adjacent minipages (0.5\textwidth}.