# How to add a force nested tables

Tags: tables

I have some data tables and I want to add a force nested table, i.e. something like the following:

[image]

after reading the comments  [tex.stackexchange.com/a/5770](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5770/), this solution is not suitable for my purposes :
1- I need to show in the caption Table instead of Figure on both sides.
2- the table doesn't show up, by using Figure tag.

[image]

code :

```
                \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
                \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
                \usepackage{adjustbox}
                \usepackage{multirow}
                \usepackage{graphicx}
                \usepackage{amsmath}
                \usepackage{algorithm}
                \usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
                \usepackage{array}
                \usepackage{makecell}
                        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
                        \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
                        \usepackage{lmodern}
                        \usepackage{graphicx}
                        \usepackage{caption}

                \begin{document}

                \begin{figure}
                    \centering
                    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
                        \centering
                        \begin{table}
                        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
                            \hline
                            \multirow{2}{*}{\thead{Data \\ I}} & \multirow{2}{*}{P} &\multirow{2}{*}{\thead{A \\ 0T}} & \multirow{2}{*}{CT}\\
                             & & & \\ 
                            \hline
                            AAA&65.77&85.42&51.35\\
                            AAT&4.6&59.4&0.6\\
                            \hline
                            Mean&39.8&39.8&39.8\\
                            \hline
                            \end{tabular}
                        \end{table}
                        \caption{Table 1}
                    \end{minipage}\hfill
                    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
                        \centering
                        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-b} % second figure itself
                        \caption{second figure}
                    \end{minipage}
                \end{figure}

                \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [Tex.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Could you please post an [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: Hi, welcome. That is similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5770/ (just replace `figure` with `table`, and add a `tabular` instead of `\includegraphics`).

Comment: welcome to tex.se! what is the problem? where you stuck, when you try to write your table?

Comment: Sir @TorbjørnT. I have tested that, but no good results

Comment: Then can you show us what you have tried, and explain what is wrong with the result?

Comment: okay @TorbjørnT. just a moment I will post it

Comment: Change `\begin{figure}` to `\begin{table}`, change `\end{figure}` to `\end{table}`, and remove the `\begin{table}` and `\end{table}` you have added around the `tabular`.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Torbjørn T

The solution is :

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
    \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{adjustbox}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{algorithm}
    \usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{makecell}
            \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
            \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
            \usepackage{lmodern}
            \usepackage{graphicx}
            \usepackage{caption}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}

        \centering
        \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
            \centering

            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
                \hline
                \multirow{2}{*}{\thead{Data \\ I}} & \multirow{2}{*}{P} &\multirow{2}{*}{\thead{A \\ 0T}} & \multirow{2}{*}{CT}\\
                 & & & \\ 
                \hline
                AAA&65.77&85.42&51.35\\
                AAT&4.6&59.4&0.6\\
                \hline
                Mean&39.8&39.8&39.8\\
                \hline
                \end{tabular}

            \caption{Average errors}
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
            \centering
            \centering

            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
                \hline
                \multirow{2}{*}{\thead{Data \\ I}} & \multirow{2}{*}{P} &\multirow{2}{*}{\thead{A \\ 0T}} & \multirow{2}{*}{CT}\\
                 & & & \\ 
                \hline
                AAA&65.77&85.42&51.35\\
                AAT&4.6&59.4&0.6\\
                \hline
                Mean&39.8&39.8&39.8\\
                \hline
                \end{tabular}

            \caption{Average success}
        \end{minipage}

    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```