# Embed two {Standalone} in {article} with /minipage

Tags: cross-referencing, minipage, include, standalone, includegraphics

I have to embed four documents{standalone} in another document{article}. `\includestandalone` is not working for me. (I have the data in the same folder, therefore the `/./`)
I tried to include with this code:

```
\begin{figure} \includestandalone[width=\textwidth]
{/./name_of_document_to_embedd} 
\caption{My TikZ picture}
\label{..} 
\end{figure}
```

Ps.: Furthermore I'm asked to include a `\ref{..}` so it's possible to put a reference to the graphics and put two document-plots next to each other with `\minipage` (but first I need to solve the including problem).

.

.

[image: Errors returned]

Comment: What does "not work" mean?

Comment: If `yourdiagram.tex` is in the same folder as your main `.tex` file, then use `\includestandalone{yourdiagram}`. You could use `\includestandalone{./yourdiagram}`, but that isn't needed. `\includestandalone{/./yourdiagram}` is wrong.

Comment: With "not working" is ment i got several errors (screenshot coming) and i tried different versions for giving the path; ./ or putting nothing in front of the name is both giving errors too.

Comment: Try not using ä in the filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning in your screenshot might give a hint to the cause. Note it looks for a filename `Attraktivit\IeC{\"a}t_...`. Probably best to stick to only the English alphabet in filenames, and not use `ä`.

As for side by side figures, the usual method (e.g. [Two figures side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5769/)) works fine. Make sure you place the `\label` after or within the `\caption`, and cross references with `\ref` etc. works as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}

%---------
% the following is only to make the example self-contained
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{draw_ing.tex}
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node{foo};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
%---------

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
  \includestandalone[width=\textwidth]{draw_ing} 
  \caption{My TikZ picture}
  \label{a}
\end{minipage} 
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
  \includestandalone[width=\textwidth]{draw_ing} 
  \caption{My TikZ picture}
  \label{b}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

See figure \ref{a} or \ref{b}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solved my problem completly, thank you very much and enjoy this sunday.