# placing three images, two side by side both below the first one in a twocolumn class

Tags: graphics

I would like to have something like on the picture for the layout of three images.
I am in twocolumn class and I know or how to place two images one above the other or side by side but not how to do both operations at the same time. Particurarly I tried 'inserting' the code part wrote on :

[Placing two images side by side in a twocolumn document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/463427/placing-two-images-side-by-side-in-a-twocolumn-document) (see the accepted answer)

into

```
 \begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.49\textwidth}
     \includegraphics[width=0.96\linewidth,clip]{apparatusXDET}
    \caption{}
    \label{fig:1} 
  \end{subfigure}
```

HERE, at this point I inserted the linked part

```
  \end{figure}
```

Unfortunately it says that two packages (subcaption and subfigure) are not compatible one with each other.
Anyone has a idea how to do it?

:[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
 \documentclass[twocolumn,prl,nobalancelastpage,aps,10pt]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{subcaption} 
 \begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.9\linewidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{cu}
   \caption{Too much coffee.}
  \end{subfigure}
  \label{fig:coffee3} 
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{cu}
     \caption{Coffee.}
   \end{subfigure}
   \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.3\linewidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{cu}
   \caption{More coffee.}
   \end{subfigure}
    \caption{The same cup of coffee. Multiple times.}
   \end{figure}
   \end{document}
```

try this on your code. On mine twocolumns class document worked well. You need just to play with the WIDTH parameter to get what you want. Thanks goes to :

https://www.latex-tutorial.com/tutorials/figures/
here you can learn more and understand it better.

You can have a look here to know how to choose the space between the two images.
[Reduction of Space between two Sub-figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42968/reduction-of-space-between-two-sub-figures)

Comment: Please make the given code snippet compilable for a fast proof!