# Placing figures side by side with independent captions

Tags: captions, minipage

I am trying to place two figures from .pgf file input side-by-side. I want them to have independent captions (so no subfigures). I have tried using the minipage way as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}

Some words..
\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \input{figure1.pgf}
        \label{Figure1}
        \caption{This is caption for Figure 1.}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \input{figure2.pgf}
        \label{Figure2}
        \caption{This is caption for Figure 2.}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But instead of getting them side by side, I get them one below the other, like the attached picture. Tried using \scalebox{0.6} before \input the pgf but still the same behavior.. I have tried many different combinations and I can't find a way to make this work...[image]

EDIT: **This is *not* a [duplicate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5769/two-figures-side-by-side). I am importing .pgf files. My latex code is identical to the above answer but it doesn't work.**
pgf files are [here](https://a.uguu.se/DPFft8cqVVmz_code.7z) if someone needs to test.

Comment: No it is not, my latex code is identical to that answer. I am also importing .pgf files, not image files.

Comment: You should give the full compileable code that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. As well as the code that generates the `.pgf` files

Comment: (i) images can be side-by side, if they are small enough (ii) to put them in parallel, they should be in the same float environment.

Comment: @ AndreC: here are all the files https://a.uguu.se/DPFft8cqVVmz_code.7z

Comment: @ Zarko: Tried to use \scalebox{0.3}{\input{figure1.pgf}} they become very small but still not in the same row.

Comment: do you put in the same float? there should not be empty spaces between `\input`.

Comment: @bomberb17 Is your problem caused by the `llncs` class? Try using another class as the native `article` class.  Likewise many packages are not necessary. Please provide a minimum complete example (MWE). Also, is it important that the images are `.pgf` extended? Does the problem arise with `.png` images? `.eps`? etc

Comment: I need to use llncs. the problem is not caused by it however, I tried also with article and I get the same thing. I also deleted all packages except {pgf} and still the same thing, so the packages are not the problem. Yes I need to keep .pfg, do not want to use .png etc.

Comment: @Zarko yes I use the same float without empty spaces

Comment: that we can help you please provide complete small document (beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`  and example of your pgf images (unfortunately i haven't any pgf image on my system).

Comment: I have already provided these above in a reply to AndreC, please download them from the link..

Comment: @AndreC: I edited the question. All I added were a couple of lines with the documentclass and the usepackage{pgf}, then nested this into begin..end document. I cannot post directly the pgf files in my question, they are in the link. However I suppose any "test" pgf file would do.

Comment: To all of you who marked as duplicate: please read my question, I explain in the bottom why the other question you linked is **different** with the one here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89523/discussion-between-andrec-and-bomberb17).

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I had to remove the two intermediate 
`\end{figure}`
`\begin{figure}`
and enclose everything into the same figure. 
So the code now looks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}

Some words..
\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \scalebox{0.45}{\input{figure1.pgf}}
        \label{Figure1}
        \caption{This is caption for Figure 1.}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \scalebox{0.45}{\input{figure2.pgf}}
        \label{Figure2}
        \caption{This is caption for Figure 2.}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]
Thanks also to Johannes_B and AndréC for helping!

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. Apart from the file extension, the main difference between the code in your question and that in the [accepted answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5770/156366) to the alleged duplicate was precisely the `\end{figure}`+`\begin{figure}` that you've now removed.

Comment: That, and the use of `\scalebox`.

Comment: Yes I was just going to write that. It turns out you have to use `\scalebox` for .pgf files.

Comment: You could also try `\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\input{figure1.pgf}}`. That scales the figure to precisely the width of the `minipage`. See the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf) for [`graphicx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx).

Comment: Yes I confirm this works as well