# How to place two pictures next to each other?

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning

I added two photos in Latex. I want these two pictures to be placed next to each other. Note that two pictures are appropriate, not two sub-pictures in one picture.

```
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure/a.eps}
    \caption{This is my first picture }
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figure/b.eps}
    \caption{This is my second picture. }
\end{figure}
```

Comment: I have voted to close your question as a duplicate to [Two figures side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5769/two-figures-side-by-side). The solution of using two side by side minipages presented there will also work in your case. However, please be aware that the widths of your images must be reduced in order to make sure both images fit into the textwidth side by side.