# side by side figures in two column format on top of page

Tags: floats

I have tried this code below and got images on a document like image 2 (the colorful one).
I want to place quite  visible side by side images like picture 1 (black and white image) on top of the page in double-column format. how can i achieve this? anyone here to help?

```
 \begin{figure}%
\centering
\subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{aq.PNG} }}%
\qquad
\subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{aq.PNG} }}%
\caption{zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz}%
\label{fig:example}%
 \end{figure}
 \begin{figure}%
\centering
\subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{aq.PNG} }}%
\qquad
\subfloat[]{{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{aq.PNG} }}%
\caption{xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}%
\label{fig:example}%
 \end{figure}
```

[image]

I followed this [Two figures side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5769/two-figures-side-by-side) but its not working in my case as I am using 2 column format IEEE template

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{c.PNG} % first figure itself
        \caption{first figure}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{h.PNG} % second figure itself
        \caption{second figure}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The colorful one was created as a subfloat, what you want is to place two figures using minipage as in this question and answers https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5769/two-figures-side-by-side

Comment: I already tried that one ..its not working .. as i am using two columns format.. thats why i asked

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example that starts with `\documentclass{}` and end with `\end{document}` so everyone will be able to figure out exactly what’s going on

Comment: tried the exact same code.. i am working on IEEE two column tempalte.. and its not working on that particular template

Comment: Please consider Luis' last comment and provide code that can be compiled without modification.

Comment: \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{cc.PNG} % first figure itself
        \caption{first figure}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{ac.PNG} % second figure itself
        \caption{second figure}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

Comment: i pasted the code but the thing is i am trying this on ieee 2 column template where its not working .. and i cannot paste the two column template all code

Comment: Please don't put the code in the comments, update the question. Try to provide the information that is needed so that others are able to understand to problem without having to guessing a lot.

Comment: 1. you can change your code to `\documentclass{IEEEtran}`. Even though it does not come with the TeXLive installation it's not hard to find the class. 2. I tried with IEEEtran and using `\begin{figure*}` seemed to have solved the problem neatly (as Zarko suggests in his answer).

Answer (score 5):

I guess, that you looking for the following:

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%{c.PNG} % first figure itself
        \caption{first figure}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-duck}%{h.PNG} % second figure itself
        \caption{second figure}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2-7]

\end{document}
```

Result of MWE is:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

As you can see from comparison of above code with yours, I replace `\textwidth` in with `\linewidth`, which consider width of columns. This enable to put figures in one column. You also can use `\columnwidth` in defining minipages' widths.

**Edit:**
Using `\textwidth` make width of your images almost equal to width of column. Consequently, in `ieeetran` document class it can not be fit in one column. In the case, that you really like to have so wide images (appearing on the top of the next page from point of their inserting into document), than you need replace in above MWE (Minimal Working Example) `figure` with `figure*`. In this case you will get:

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)

**Addendum:**
From OP comment below answer I conclude, that (s)he is interested for send case, where in each `minipage` are two images:

[image]

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure*}[t]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\hfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
        \caption{first figure}
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
\hfill
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\linewidth]{example-image-duck}
        \caption{second figure}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
\lipsum[2-20]

\end{document}
```

Comment: like you placed two figures in the left column in first image .. exactly I want to place these two images on the right column too (s total of 4 figures these should be at top of page)

Comment: Yea i edited my question again for clear understanding .. I need to place four figures in a row on top of page in two-column format. The figure like highlighted with red pen. and Thankyou so much

Comment: Thank you @Zarko for this answer, +1.