# Placing different kinds of tikz drawings side by side with captions

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, horizontal-alignment, minipage, tikz-cd

Lots of people have approached this question, but none with the twist I think I am suffering from. I am using diagrams both in regular tikzcd and from quiver. I want to place them side by side and to include captions for them. Here is my tex. I get odd errors related to not being in outer par mode, having an undefined control sequence, and missing a number.

Here is the code with some revision:

```
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}
        \begin{tikzcd}
                %\node (point) at (0,0) [circle, fill=yellow, radius=0.3cm] {};
             \draw [fill=black, draw=none] (-0.40,0.25) circle (0.18cm)
                 node (pt1) {};
             \draw [fill=black, draw=none] (0.45, -0.25) circle (0.18cm)
                  node (pt2) {};

             %\node (root) at (0,0) [draw=black, circle, radius=1cm] {};
             \draw [draw=black, ultra thick] (0,0) circle (0.80cm)
                 node (planet) {};
             %\node [below = 1cm, align=flush center, text width=5cm]
             %{
                %    A set
             %};
            \end{tikzcd}{\caption{A diagram}}

    \end{figure}

\end{minipage}


\begin{minipage}{0.2\textwidth}

    \begin{figure}
        \[\begin{tikzcd}
            \bullet \\
            \\
            \bullet && \bullet \\
            \\
            && \bullet
            \arrow[from=3-1, loop left]
            \arrow[from=3-1, to=3-3]
            \arrow[from=5-3, to=1-1,  crossing over]
            
        \end{tikzcd}\]{\caption{Another figure}}

    \end{figure}
\end{minipage}
\end{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
```

Let me know how I can improve my question if need be.

Comment: Hi, welcome. Put the `minipage`s inside a single `figure` environment as in e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5770/

Comment: you can not put figure inside a minipage (or any box) you will get an error "not in outer par mode" place the minipage with the images inside the figure

Comment: thanks giving it a shot

Comment: Ok it worked, but the figures are not centered. `\center` does not seem to fix it

Comment: It should be `\centering`, not `\center`.

Comment: I take it the minipages are for the captions as well as aligning the centers.

Comment: Yeah, thanks @JasperHabicht that did the trick. I am now using it all over the place!