# Place two images next to each other within a given class

Tags: graphics, line-breaking

For a paper, I am using the following class:

`\documentclass[utf8]{frontiersSCNS}`

Within this class, I would like to place two images next to each other. None of [these answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5769/two-figures-side-by-side) work for me.

The code below works, but locates pictures below each other instead of next to each other.

```
\begin{figure}[!tbp]
  \centering
  {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Interpretability VS. AUC_20.pdf}}
  \hfill
  {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Interpretability VS. AUC_all.pdf}}
  \caption{Coherence scores for topic models with the top 10 and 20 words.}
  \label{fig:coherence_linechart}
\end{figure}
```

How can I get my images next to each other into one picture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider your code (with line numbers added for reference):

```
1: \begin{figure}[!tbp]
2:   \centering
3:   {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Interpretability VS. AUC_20.pdf}}
4:   \hfill
5:   {\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Interpretability VS. AUC_all.pdf}}
6:   \caption{Coherence scores for topic models with the top 10 and 20 words.}
7:   \label{fig:coherence_linechart}
8: \end{figure}
```

Without a [line-ending `%`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764) on line 3 you're effectively introducing an additional space after the first image. Since you're scaling both images to `0.5\textwidth`, together they won't fit within the text block horizontally since the additional space makes the entire line wider than `\textwidth`. Either introduce a line-ending `%` after the first image (and remove the unnecessary `\hfill`), or reduce the scaling to tolerate a space between the two images:

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{<image_1>}%
  \hfill
  \includegraphics[width=0.49\linewidth]{<image_2>}%

  \caption{<caption>}
  \label{<label>}
\end{figure}
```