# Tikz diagrams in align and captions

Tags: tikz-pgf, align, captions, tikz-arrows

I have two Tikz diagrams - let's denote their code by $D$ and $D'$. Now I want to display them in a row, so I put them in align. That is I write

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
 
\begin{align}
D  & & D'
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

In addition I would like to put a caption under each diagram. I tried to use the caption software, but doesn't seem to work in the align environment. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why do you want to use the `align` environment? Are your TikZ diagrams actually equations? If not just write them without a blank line (→ new paragraph) between them. Horizontal alignment can be adjusted with the `center` environment or the `\centering` command inside a `figure` environment, the `minipage` environment (or even with TikZ itself). The `subcaption` package or related ones can help with adding captions to each diagram. There are many Qs about this on this site.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirel: Thanks for the all the suggestions. Unfortunately I am getting a bit confused. Could you write out a short example? Or direct me to some of the Q&As on the site.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5769/1952. Replace the `\includegraphics` by your `TiKZ` figures and you will get it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it, adopting the comments, mainly [from Ignasi](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/683804/tikz-diagrams-in-align-and-captions#comment1696602_683804):

[image: result]

Kindly check the [package documentation from subfigure at ctan](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) for details.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}       % for Tikz
\usepackage{lipsum}     % some blindtext
\usepackage{subfigure}  % assuming both figures belong together somehow

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[10] See figure \ref{fig}.

    \begin{figure}[!h]
        \centering
        \subfigure[Left demo]{% "split", just to show the structure
            \tikz{% <<< put those % to avoid insertion of unwanted spaces, i.e. shifts
                \draw (0,0) rectangle (3,2);%
            }%
        }
        \hspace{2cm}% some extra horizontal separation
        \subfigure[Right demo]{\tikz{\draw[fill=green!20] (0,0) rectangle (2,3);}}
    \caption{Two demo figures with Tikz}\label{fig}
    \end{figure}
    
    \lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

Comment: `subfigure` is obsolete package. Use `subfig` or even better `subcation` instead it!

Comment: Good to know. Nice hint.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear about how you like to present your figures. With captions or without it? As subfigures in figure or as two independent figures Or figure with two images? Hence MWE (Minimal Working Example) below contain all three listed scenarios:

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
%--------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%
\usepackage{lipsum}                             % for dummy text
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66] 
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\subfloat[Left demo \label{subfig:a}]{\tikz\node[draw] {left subfigure};}
\hfil
\subfloat[Right demo \label{subfig:b}]{\tikz\node[draw] {right subfigure};}

\caption{As two sub figures drawn with  Ti*k*Z}\
\label{fig}
    \end{figure}
    
As you can see in subfigure \ref{subfig:a} in figure \ref{fig} \dots

    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}\centering
\tikz\node[draw] {left figure};
\caption{Your left figure drawn by Ti*k*Z package}
\label{fig:a}
\end{minipage}
\hfil
\begin{minipage}{0.45\linewidth}\centering
\tikz\node[draw] {right figure};
\caption{Your right figure drawn by Ti*k*Z package}
\label{fig:b}
\end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
As you can see in figure \ref{fig:a} and figure \ref{fig:b} \dots

At the end also example, when sub figures haven't own captions:
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\tikz\node[draw, text width=0.4\linewidth] {left figure drawn using Ti*k*Z package};
\hfil
\tikz\node[draw, text width=0.4\linewidth] {right figure drawn using Ti*k*Z package};

\caption{As two images in figure, drawn with  Ti*k*Z}
\label{fig:3}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines only shows text block area)

Comment: how to say? Can you please check the documentclass? Thank you.

Comment: @MS-SPO, huh, it is not showing due to bad markup of code but it is present in answer. Already corrercted.