# Why is this side-by-side graphic code, based on example from here, not working?

Tags: graphics

I followed the example from here [Two figures side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5769/two-figures-side-by-side) to create the following code:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption} 
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{pics/NormalCalc1}
        \caption{Fig 1}
        \end{minipage} \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{pics/NormalCalc2}
        \caption{Fig 2}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But I get the following output. I can't see what I'm doing wrong (the example in the post clearly worked!).

[image]

Comment: delete the space between the minipages you have two 1/2 width minipage with a word-space in between, so they do not fit on a line.

Comment: the referenced code has `\end{minipage}\hfill` not `\end{minipage} \hfill` and used `{0.45\textwidth}` not `{0.5\textwidth}` to leave some space between

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. Thanks for bailing me out once again. Sorry to be so dim.